# Pointing Nginx to Gunicorn on a different server

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, lxc

I have a bunch of different services running across several lxc containers, including Django apps.

What I want to do is install Nginx on the Host machine and proxy pass to the Gunicorn instance running in an lxc container. The idea is that custom domain names and certs are added on the Host and the containers remain unchanged for different installs.

it works if I proxy_pass from the host to nginx running in a container, but I then have issues with csrf, which for the Django admin, cannot be turned off.

Thus, what I would like to do is only run nginx on the host server connecting to the Gunicorn instance on the lxc container.

Not sure if that will fix the csrf issues, but it does not seem right to run multiple nginx instances

Comment: What stops you from running nginx on the server and configure it to proxy pass incoming connections on certain ports to certain containers?

Comment: Thats kinda what i want to know. How do i proxy pass to the gunicorn server on the container and not to an nginx services on the container